# my android service cannot start after booting device

Tags: android, android-intent

I bet it's repeated question but I need to ask it again. Service cannot start even I've put following code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastreceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>         

    <activity
        android:name="com.im.HomeActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.im.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.im.SyncService"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </service>
</application>
```

and

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");          
    }   
}
```

Help me, please.

Comment: *"Service cannot start"* How do you know? Any error messages? Is `MyBroadcastreceiver#onReceive()` called? What does `startService()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `BraodcastReciever` getting invoked?

if not then the reason  could be following:

> Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a
>   “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user
>   explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this
>   state.
>
> once the user runs the app for the first time (and does not Force Stop
>   it), everything behaves as before — a reboot will cause BOOT_COMPLETED
>   broadcasts to be received and so on. However, if the user installs the
>   app, until and unless they run the app manually, no broadcasts will be
>   received.

So in your case you will have to create launcher activity and make sure you start that launcher activity at least once then you will start receive boot event broadcast.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098926/android-bootreceiver-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 3.1, a user must start the application at least once before your application can receive `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` events.

Also `android:allowBackup="true"` is set in your manifest file, make sure the App is **not** installed on the SD card. If you are saving to external storage, you will need to set`android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE` instead.

On some phones(like HTC) there is a *Fast Boot* option, If it is activated, The `BOOT_COMPLETE` will not be invoked.

Another approach would be to use `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and check if service is running, if it isn't, then start the service. More info available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411731/how-to-get-boot-complete-intent-in-htc-when-i-use-poweroff-for-reboot)